# Enum Class not visible in the same folder level

Tags: java, class, enums

I'm trying to access an enum type from a separate file, which is in the same folder level as the class I'm trying to access it from.

These are the two files:

Number.java:

```
public enum Number {
    ONE, TWO, THREE
}
```

mainClass.java:

```
public class mainClass {

    private Number numVar;

    mainClass(Number num) {
        numVar = num;
    }
}
```

However, mainClass doesn't recognise 'Number' as a valid type. Specifically 'Number' cannot be resolved to a type. Any idea why?

Comment: add in question yuor project structure

Comment: when they are both at root package level, it should work. Bad practice, certainly. You should always define a package (even standard java classes have a package java.* ). If you don't specify a package the classes must be in the root folder of your source tree.

Answer (score 3):

`Number` is a standard class in Java.
You should rename your Enum or reference it through

```java
private you_package.Number numVar;
```

But I suggest you to rename you Enum and never name any class/enum as a standard one. Here's [the official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html) of this class.

Comment: The purpose of packages is to avoid class name conflicts. I agree Number is not the best name to use but defined in a different package there is no problem in defining the same class names. It will only annoy users when importing these classes but that will probably become the OP's own problem :)

Comment: Side note: other case of this problem is when people are trying to write some simple game/simulation and are wondering why their `Character` (as person/player/avatar) class behave strangely, since Java also has its own `java.lang.Character` class corresponding to `char` which causes naming conflicts as `java.lang` package is by default added to any class (like implicit `import java.lnag.*;`)